# How to make WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount work without unique username

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a default ASP.NET MVC 4 project with an account controller that uses forms authentication.
Now I would like to make user accounts to be not unique only within a given system instance (each user have its own SystemInstanceId) in a way that you:

- Can use username1 within system instance for company 1 (website_address/company1) and the same username1 within a system instance for company 2 (website_address/company2)
- Can not use username1 within one system instance

.

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int SystemInstanceId { get; set; }
}
```

In AccountController I use the following code but it does not work as I want it to:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
    model.UserName, 
    model.Password, 
    propertyValues: new { SystemInstanceId = systemInstanceRepository.GetCurrentSystemInstanceId(RouteSegmentHelpers.GetSystemInstanceSegment(RouteData)) }
);
```

Code above makes me unable to register the same user name within database table for two different system instances which is against my design, because I want users to be able to use the same logins for different companies.